# Один класс для двух форм

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли сделать так чтобы `Form1` и `From2` ссылались на один класс? Изначально была только `Form1`, после добавилась `From2` с почти теми же функциями что и на `Form1`. Чтобы не делать все заново, нужно чтобы и `Form2` ссылалась на класс который изначально создавался для `Form1`.

Comment: Конечно. Вы можете создать базовую форму и от нее сделать наследование этих двух форм.

Comment: Можно, это называется наследование.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: А лучше весь функционал вынести в отдельный(е) класс(ы) и уйти от `Smart GUI`. В форму передавать только экземпляр этого функционального класса

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то конечно можно.

Выглядит это примерно следующим образом:

```
public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Где `BaseForm` - класс базовой формы для других форм. Для второй формы аналогично.

Так же можно почитать тут: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bx1155fz(v=vs.110).aspx